# Wi-fi disabled via hardware

Tags: wireless, hardware

I found already similar questions, but I wasn't able to solve my problem, I hope this want be a clone thread.

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on my HP-Pavilion-Notebook, partitioning the hard disk (I have Windows 10 too).

When I start Ubuntu I've no wireless problems, but if I close my laptop and reopen it, wifi becomes "disabled via hardware", and it seems I've no other choice than restart my computer. I tried to upgrade software, but it didn't worked.

Many thanks and sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: Open setting, wifi, and activate

Comment: It does not work. I don't think it's that trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Does your netbook have a physical wi-fi on/off switch? If that is the case, try turning it off and then on again. See [My wireless connection (or other hardware) does not work when I wake up my computer](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html.en)

Comment: No it doesn't. Possibly is a problem of the Drivers, but I can't find a way to solve the problem different from reboot the laptop.